# Как вставить PHP код в html

Tags: php, html

Не вставляется PHP код, вернее вставляется до знака ">"(меньше) в седьмой строчке.

```
<body>
  <?php
    echo "test";

    $mybd = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "php_ABIN",3306);
    if(!$mybd){
      die(json_encode(["ERROR"=>"BAD_SQL_CONN"]));
    }
  ?>
 </body>
```

[image: Сайт выглядит так:]

Comment: ваш сервер не настроен на обработку файлов html как php скриптов. Либо переименуйте расширение файла в php, либо перенастройте сервер

Comment: Для теста используйте встроенный сервер php -S localhost:8000 -t {path to project}  Не стоит заморачиваться сразу с серьёзными серверами. Ещё, просто открыв файл, вы ничего не увидите, что ожидали. Запустите сервер, потом http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php

Comment: @ArchDemon в адресной строке видно, что сервера вообще нет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файлы с кодом `php` обрабатываются в первую очередь сервером. Поэтому просто открыв файл в браузере - **ничего из php никогда не будет отображено**. Надо открывать файл минимум по корректному пути **на сервере**. Возможно в текущем случае это `localhost/index.html`

Также обычно по умолчанию сервер обрабатывает код только в файлах с расширением `php`.  Поэтому надо посмотреть настройки сервера и если там нет нужной строчки в виде

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
```

где среди прочих есть ещё `html`, то даже при запуске на сервере ничего не произойдёт. И надо либо дописать строчку, либо поменять расширение файла на `php`